# VASP geometry optimization not converging

Tags: vasp, geometry-optimization

I have tried everything I could find online but I am not able to relax this structure in VASP. I started out with the basic INCAR

```
 SYSTEM   =  Perovskite

# Electronic minimization
  ISTART  = 0
  ICHARG  = 2
  IALGO    = 38
  PREC= Accurate
  ENCUT   = 400
  NELM    = 200
  EDIFF   = 1E-6
  EDIFFG  =-0.03
  LWAVE   =.FALSE.
  IVDW    = 11
  ISYM    = 0

# Ionic minimization
  NSW     = 200
  IBRION  = 2
  ISIF    = 2
  POTIM   = 0.5
  PSTRESS = 109

# Exchange correlational functional
  GGA = PE

 ISMEAR   = 0
 SIGMA    = 0.02

  NCORE = 4
```

Additionally I have tried changing the "ALGO" tag and even break down the calculations into "ISIF=2" and then "ISIF=3". I also tried changing IBRION tag and checking the inital geometry but nothing is working.

For the case of ISIF=2 the calculation stops after 1st scf iteration and gives the error `WARNING: CNORMN: search vector ill defined`. If I try using ISIF=3 then the geometry goes even farther away from the minima and the energy goes to values as high +4000.

A thing of note is that I am relaxing this under Hydrostatic pressure, but this should not lead to problems as I have relaxed similar structures. The issue is arising probably from the fact that geometry is just too far away from the minima.

What can I do to get a convergence on this relaxation?

```
Cs2 Sn I6
1.0
        9.0550003052         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         7.3959999084         0.0000000000
       -0.6390889480         0.0000000000         8.6203423505
   Cs   Sn    I
    4    2   12
Direct
     0.496004999         0.000000000         0.750850022
     0.503995001         0.000000000         0.249149993
     0.996004999         0.500000000         0.250850022
     0.003995001         0.500000000         0.749149978
     0.000000000         0.000000000         0.000000000
     0.500000000         0.500000000         0.500000000
    -0.176189019         0.000000000         0.209978808
     0.809142163         0.265969992        -0.192556779
     0.809142163         0.734030008        -0.192556779
     0.190857836         0.265969992         1.192556816
     0.190857836         0.734030008         1.192556816
     1.176189019         0.000000000         0.790021191
     0.690857841         0.765969992         0.692556774
     0.309142163         0.234030008         0.307443183
     0.309142163         0.765969992         0.307443183
     0.690857841         0.234030008         0.692556774
     0.323810980         0.500000000         0.709978808
     0.676189019         0.500000000         0.290021191
```

Comment: This suggests (a) checking for duplicate atoms, and (b) using `ALGO = A` in place of `IALGO = 38`. https://dannyvanpoucke.be/vasp-errors-en/

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Please update us! Was the comment by @AndreyPoletayev helpful?